# How can I reproduce the result of AgeEstimation model in MXNet-Python?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mxnet-format

How can I reproduce the result of AgeEstimation model in MXNet-Python?

[here](https://github.com/HyperGroups/MachineLearning/tree/master/mxnet/python) is my repo about MXnet-Python codes to load Mathematica Models.

I want the result of Mathematica and the result of MXNet-Python are the same or closely.

For example:

"Age Estimation VGG-16 Trained on IMDB-WIKI Data"

[image]

I've also extracted a Mean Image, so you can implement into MXNet-Python, if necessary.

One result of this little_girl image in one version MXNet-Python is

`[ 23  50  27  18  19  25  26  54  29  21  33  58  17  24  22  28  49  20
  48  51  53  34  30  40  52  46  43  36  37  45  41  35  47  32  15  44
  56  38  55  60  57  61  39  63  16  31  59  42  13  64  14  65  12  11
  62  10  69  68  67  71  66   9   8  70  79  72  75  73  74  76  77   7
  78   1   5   6  80  84  82  81   4   2  83  85  86  87   0   3  90  88
  89  91  96  93  92 100  94  95  98  99  97]`

[image]

Comment: "I found in this codes, AgeEstimation is very challenging": If you read the example page for this model, it tells you it expects an image of their face ("Predict a person's age from an image of their face"). Hence why its doing terribly here.

Comment: @Sebastian I've extracted an MeanImage, is it enough?

Comment: @Sebastian but even I use  my croped face image, the result in Mathematica is also hard to reproduce in MXNet-Python

Answer (score 3):

I get a better result if I use `FindFaces` as a basis to crop the image.

---

Get the same image and net model that you're using:

```
img = Import["https://github.com/HyperGroups/MachineLearning/blob/master/mxnet/python/Data/little_girl.jpg?raw=true"];

model = NetModel["Age Estimation VGG-16 Trained on IMDB-WIKI Data"]
```

Use `FindFaces` to get a bounding box, then post-process it a bit.  Two things are done: pad the bounding box by 50% on each side since `FindFaces` gives a very tight box and a bit more visual context is useful, and convert from x-y coordinates to row-column so that we can use `ImageTake`.

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];

s = .5; 
faces = FindFaces[img, "BoundingBox"] /. 
    Rectangle[{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}] :> 
        {Reverse[{h - Clip[ymin - s (ymax - ymin), {0, h}], 
                  h - Clip[ymax + s (ymax - ymin), {0, h}]}], 
        {Clip[xmin - s (xmax - xmin), {0, w}], 
         Clip[xmax + s (xmax - xmin), {0, w}]}}
```

Extract the faces and apply the age estimation model:

```
faceimages = ImageTake[img, ##] & @@@ faces

model /@ faceimages
```

[image]

Depending on the amount of padding (values of `s` between 0 and 1), I've gotten estimates of 10, 13, and 19.